# how to use the display command of pdb python module?

Tags: python, pdb

display expression: prints out the value of an expression each time it gets changed. This is useful for monitoring the value of variables that get changed in loops. So, suppose the following is the code:

```
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        a=f(i,j)
```

I know something is wrong with the execution of `a=f(i,j)` for certain values of i and j. Then, how to use the display command from pdb module to find out the values of i and j when it does not work? I suppose when you use display command, it will display the value of i and j automatically, right? Do I need to combine the c command and b command from pdb module also? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Please do  not down vote it. I need help.

Answer (score 1):

`display` sets a "watch", so that each time execution stops (whether by completing a `next`, a `step`, or an `until`, or breaking on a `continue` ), if the value has changed, it will print a message showing the old value and the new value.

Since you know something is wrong with your `f` function, your easiest solution is to put a `break` on that function, and set display of the inputs inside that scope.  Since you have shown us nothing about `f`, I don't know what the input variables will be called at that level, but it's likely that it won't be "i" and "j", so set the display appropriately.

I find display most useful for when I'm stepping through code that involves loops, using `n` or `s` or `c`.  It keeps track of variables for me, and saves me from having to `print` the variables I'm interested in.  If you know your problem is in f, you'll have to step through the code there yourself, and check all the variables at all the interesting statements. If you find yourself checking a variable repeatedly, that's where you use `display`.